# dxDatagrid LookUp column DataSource

Tags: javascript, devexpress

Здравствуйте. Использую devExpress для js есть таблица dxdataGrid
c datasource и столбец реализующий выпадающий список через lookup, ссылающийся на свой dataSource, Пагинация включена в обоих случаях

```
    this.$scope.dxGridLocalConfig = {
        dataSource: AService.dataSource,
        paging: {
            enabled: true,
            pageSize: 25
        },
        columns: [{
                    dataField: 'SId',
                    caption: 'S',
                    lookup: {
                       dataSource: {
                          store: SService.store,
                          paginate: true,
                          pageSize: 25,                    
                       },
                       valueExpr: 'Id',
                       displayExpr: 'FullName'
                     }                    
  }]
}
```

проблема заключается в том что загрузке страницы с таким гридом,
Сначала идет запрос на источник с данными с учетом пагинации для всей таблицы (я использую odata DataSource)

```
http://localhost/odata/A?%24orderby=Id&%24top=25&%24count=true
```

затем идет запрос к

```
http://localhost/odata/S
```

который запрашивает **ВСЕ** записи вместо того что бы или ничего не запрашивать или только первые 25.
DataSource у меня описаны через

```
this.store = ODataService.context.S;
this.dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: this.store,
    paginate: true,
    pageSize: 25,
});
```

и контекст в свою очередь

```
this.context = new DevExpress.data.ODataContext({
                url: `localhost/odata/`,
                entities: {
                    S: {
                        key: 'Id',
                        keyType: 'Int32'
                    },
```

При это при щелчке внутри связанного поля, открывается поле с прокруткой и отрабатывает как надо, то есть есть постепенная подгрузка запросами вида

```
http://localhost/odata/S?%24skip=50&%24top=25
```

Единственно чего я хочу избежать это загрузки всех данных из связанных полей, потому как данных там очень много и получается что в таблице с 3мя записями в фоновом режиме тянется еще 1,5млн, соответственно все это очень тормозит. Так быть не должно

UPD: Подготовил (точнее адаптировал) пример проблемы

```js
/// <reference path="C:/Program Files (x86)/DevExpress 16.1/DevExtreme/Sources/Lib/ts/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="C:/Program Files (x86)/DevExpress 16.1/DevExtreme/Sources/Lib/ts/dx.all.d.ts" />

$(function() {
  var context = new DevExpress.data.ODataContext({
    url: "http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/",
    entities: {
      Categories: {
        key: "CategoryID",
        keyType: "Int32",
      },
      Suppliers: {
        key: "SupplierID",
        keyType: "Int32",

      },
      Products: {
        name: "Products",
        key: "ProductID",
        expand: ["Category"],
        keyType: "Int32"
      }
    },
    version: 4
  })
  $("#grid").dxDataGrid({
    dataSource: context.Products,       
    paging: {
      enabled: true,
      pageSize: 1
    },
    columns: ["ProductID", {
        dataField: "ProductName",
      },
      {
        dataField: "SupplierID",
        lookup: {
          dataSource: {
            store: context.Suppliers,
            paginate: true,
            pagesize: 3
          },
          displayExpr: "ContactName",
          valueExpr: "SupplierID"
        }
      },
      {
        dataField: "CategoryID",
        lookup: {
          dataSource: {
            store: context.Categories,
            paginate: true,
            pagesize: 3
          },
          displayExpr: "CategoryName",
          valueExpr: "CategoryID"
        }
      }
    ],
    pagesize: 5,
    filterRow: {
      visible: true
    },
    headerFilter: {
      visible: true
    },
    groupPanel: {
      visible: true
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>DevExtreme jQuery site</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.5/css/dx.common.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.5/css/dx.light.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.5/js/dx.all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="16.2.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

установлена размер страницы в 1 запись, но при загрузке страницы Suppliers при помощи запроса получают все 29 (а если бы их было не 29 а 1.5 млн) хотя нужна всего то одна, чтобы полностью отобразить страницу. может я где косячу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это особенность работы лукапа в гриде - постраничная загрузка отключается всегда. Делается это в связи с тем, что в гриде как правило отображается несколько строк, и в каждой строке лукап должен отобразить текст, соответсвующий значению внешнего ключа.

Обычный лукап (не встроенный в грид) получает этот текст из  dataSource, что в случае постраничной загрузки приводит к запросу на сервис. Но в гриде, если следовать принципу повторного использования кода, в таком случае будет сделано N запросов, где N это количество страниц по которым разбросаны внешние ключи. Это может привести к заметным задержкам при загрузке грида. В **общем случае** эффективнее загрузить dataSource целиком, и выбирать из него нужные элементы перечисляя их в памяти.

Я подчеркнул "в общем случае", потому что всегда существуют исключения из правил, и метод эффективный для большинства приложений будет неоправданно расточительным в некоторых частных случаях. Если лукап привязан к большой таблице, лучше не полагаться на встроенный механизм лукапа, а добавить в выборку нужные значения используя опции expand и select. Такая выборка будет эффективнее лукапа в частном случае.

```
dataSource: {
    store:context.Products,
    expand: "Supplier",
    select: ["ProductName", "Supplier.ContactName"]   
},
paging: {
  enabled: true,
  pageSize: 1
},
```

Comment: Да вариант хороший, вполне жизнеспособный